# Sails name type returning undefined instead of string

Tags: sails.js

My sails seed has been configured to place a string for the name attribute under models, however it crashes my app instead.

```
error: Bootstrap encountered an error: (see below)
error:
error: { UsageError: Invalid initial data for new records.
Details:
  Could not use one of the provided new records: Missing value for required attribute `name`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined
 [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help.
    at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (/Users/adarian/learn-sails/config/bootstrap.js:63:14)
  cause:
   { UsageError: Invalid initial data for new records.
   Details:
     Could not use one of the provided new records: Missing value for required attribute `name`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined
    [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help.
       at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (/Users/adarian/learn-sails/config/bootstrap.js:63:14)
     name: 'UsageError',
     code: 'E_INVALID_NEW_RECORDS',
     details:
      'Could not use one of the provided new records: Missing value for required attribute `name`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined' },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'E_INVALID_NEW_RECORDS',
  details:
   'Could not use one of the provided new records: Missing value for required attribute `name`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined' }
```

How do I fix this because my seed file looks like this.

```
 /**
 * Sails Seed Settings
 * (sails.config.seeds)
 *
 * Configuration for the data seeding in Sails.
 *
 * For more information on configuration, check out:
 * http://github.com/frostme/sails-seed
 */
module.exports.seeds = {
  user: [
    {
      name: "John Wayne",
      email: 'johnnie86@gmail.com',
      avatar: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/83.jpg',
      location: 'Mombasa',
      bio: 'Spends most of my time at the beach'
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the cause of the issue is due to `config/model.js` file which had listed `migrate: 'drop'` which in turn should have been `migrate: 'alter'`. I do not know why this is the wrong to set it to `drop`, but it would not work with `drop` as the option and only work with either `safe` or `alter`.